# Insert Values In Columns From Columns From A Different Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table :

```
|   Cod  |  SKA  |   SKB |   SKC  |
|   AGE  |   1   |   10  |   100  |
|   AUC  |   2   |   11  |   101  |
|   BER  |   3   |   12  |   102  |
|   AGE  |   4   |   13  |   103  |
|   AUC  |   5   |   14  |   104  |
|   BER  |   6   |   15  |   105  |
```

And I want to add those columns in an other table to have something like this :

```
|   Cod  |  SKA  |   SKB |   SKC  |
|   AGE  |   1   |   10  |   100  |
|   AGE  |   1   |   11  |   101  |
|   AGE  |   1   |   12  |   102  |
|   AGE  |   1   |   13  |   103  |
|   AGE  |   1   |   14  |   104  |
|   AUC  |   1   |   15  |   105  |
|   AUC  |   2   |   10  |   100  |
|   AUC  |   2   |   11  |   101  |
|   AUC  |   2   |   12  |   102  |
|   AUC  |   2   |   13  |   103  |
|   AUC  |   2   |   14  |   104  |
|   AUC  |   2   |   15  |   105  |
|   ...  |   ... |  ...  |   ...  |
|   ...  |   ... |  ...  |   ...  |
|   ...  |   ... |  ...  |   ...  |
```

So every Cod, SKB and SKC according to one SKA and then according to the second etc. And this for all the SK columns,

How can I have this result ? With a join ?

### EDIT

Thanks for your comment and answers I'll try a cross join !

Comment: Hmm maybe a cross join on another table, could you provide a bit more concrete example? What would the other table look like before the join? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `cross join` to get all combinations of the four columns:

```
select cod.cod, a.ska, b.skb, c.skc
from (select distinct cod from t) cod cross join
     (select distinct ska from t) a cross join
     (select distinct skb from t) b cross join
     (select distinct skc from t) c ;
```

You may need to adjust this query to meet your needs.  Your text describes one thing, but the sample data is slightly different.  I would expect `AGE/2` to be in the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by joining your table to itself with a `cross join`. However, because your `Cod` column has repeated values, you may want to select the `distinct` rows; otherwise you'll have duplicates.

```
select distinct
    t1.Cod, 
    t2.SKA, t2.SKB, t2.SKC
from
    mytable t1
    cross join mytable t2
```

See an example in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f50a01/5).